# Changing Dynamic URL to Static URL

Tags: dynamic-url

I have seo for website currencyconverterlive.com, on conversion from one currency to another currency page displaying result but URL doesn't change it displays (ie. https://currencyconverterlive.com/result.php) I want it to be (https://currencyconverterlive.com/1-usd-to-aed) for every currency result a user search exchange rates.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some code? Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am not a coder, if something moderate level changes what I can do please suggest.